# mysql select from table 1 join and order by table 2 , optimization filesort

Tags: mysql, temporary, filesort

read mysql post but couldnt find the solution.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

I have 2 tables A,B
Table A has folderid mapped to multiple feedid (1 to many )
Table B has feedid and data associated with it.

The following query gives Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort

```
SELECT A.feed_id,B.feed_id,B.entry_id 
FROM feed_folder A 
LEFT JOIN feed_data B on A.feed_id=B.feed_id 
WHERE A.folder_id=29  
AND B.entry_id <= 123 
AND B.entry_created <= '2012-11-01 21:38:54' 
ORDER by B.entry_created desc limit 0,20;
```

Any ideas as to how the temporary  filesort can be avoided.

Following is the table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `feed_folder` (
  `folder_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `feed_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `folder_id` (`folder_id`,`feed_id`),
  KEY `feed_id` (`feed_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `feed_data` (
  `entry_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `feed_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `entry_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `entry_object` text,
  `entry_permalink` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `entry_orig_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entry_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `feed_id_2` (`feed_id`,`entry_permalink`),
  KEY `entry_created` (`entry_created`),
  KEY `feed_id` (`feed_id`,`entry_created`),
  KEY `feed_id_entry_id` (`feed_id`,`entry_id`),
  KEY `entry_permalink` (`entry_permalink`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: There's a syntax error in your query B doesnt have a folder_id.

Comment: made the changes, it was a typo. It should have been A.folder_id

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT
A.feed_id,B.feed_id,B.entry_id 
FROM feed_folder as A 
INNER JOIN feed_data as B on A.feed_id=B.feed_id 
WHERE A.folder_id=29  
AND B.entry_id <= 123 
AND B.entry_created <= '2012-11-01 21:38:54')joinAndSortTable
ORDER by B.entry_created desc limit 0,20;
```

The problem is in alias, you are forgot to give `as A` and `as B`
i'm also remind you about LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN, INNER JOIN...
To join all records what you selected, Using `INNER JOIN` is a workaround.
Because `INNER JOIN` can join all columns with full accessed.

GOOD LUCK